# Pandas fillna() rows in a specific order

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan, fillna

I have problem with `fillna()` method. This is my example df, which represents quantity of items in a shop. I would like to fill all the *NaN*s. If there is a *NaN*, I would like to fill it with values from previous day or if it is *NaN*, then from the next day (the same product, the same shop). If all days for specific product and shop are *NaN*s, then I would like to fill it with 0. I am looking for the best pandas way to do it, I had some ideas with loops, but it doesn't look very well.

My df:

```
    day    shop  product  quantity
0     1  shop_A   apples       3.0
1     2  shop_A   apples       NaN
2     3  shop_A   apples       1.0
3     1  shop_A  bananas       NaN
4     2  shop_A  bananas       NaN
5     3  shop_A  bananas       NaN
6     1  shop_B   apples       NaN
7     2  shop_B   apples       NaN
8     3  shop_B   apples       2.0
9     1  shop_B  bananas       NaN
10    2  shop_B  bananas       4.0
11    3  shop_B  bananas       2.0
```

Expected df:

```
    day    shop  product  quantity
0     1  shop_A   apples       3.0
1     2  shop_A   apples       3.0
2     3  shop_A   apples       1.0
3     1  shop_A  bananas       0.0
4     2  shop_A  bananas       0.0
5     3  shop_A  bananas       0.0
6     1  shop_B   apples       2.0
7     2  shop_B   apples       2.0
8     3  shop_B   apples       2.0
9     1  shop_B  bananas       4.0
10    2  shop_B  bananas       4.0
11    3  shop_B  bananas       2.0
```

I also tried `fillna(limit=3)`, but this isn't what am I looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can sort by day using `sort_values` and then perform a grouped `bfill` and then what's left will just get a 0 with chaining a `fillna(0)`:

```
df['quantity'] = df.sort_values(by='day')\
                 .groupby(['shop','product'])['quantity'].bfill(limit=3).fillna(0)
```

prints back:

```
    day    shop  product  quantity
0     1  shop_A   apples       3.0
1     2  shop_A   apples       1.0
2     3  shop_A   apples       1.0
3     1  shop_A  bananas       0.0
4     2  shop_A  bananas       0.0
5     3  shop_A  bananas       0.0
6     1  shop_B   apples       2.0
7     2  shop_B   apples       2.0
8     3  shop_B   apples       2.0
9     1  shop_B  bananas       4.0
10    2  shop_B  bananas       4.0
11    3  shop_B  bananas       2.0
```

This will give a the value of the next day to the `NaN` value of the previous day for each shop and product. You can similarly use `ffill` (or both), and perhaps linear interpolation, and your results will change accordingly. This is however what you need to get you started.